# Add pdf export to shopware template

Tags: php, pdf-generation, smarty, shopware

How can I add a PDF generation functionality to a frontend template? There are some predefined PDF templates (for ex. invoice) but I can't find specific piece of code where they generate PDF in frontend.

Answer (score 0):

There is no frontend logic for pdf-generation in shopware. PDFs are only generated manually in the backend.

You can have a look at the Sepa Payment Method. There is an example on how to generate a pdf from a tpl file in a plugin:

https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.4/engine/Shopware/Plugins/Default/Core/PaymentMethods/Components/SepaPaymentMethod.php#L264

You will definitely need a plugin to generate a pdf in the frontend.

Comment: I found a way with Shopware_Components_Document class, I wrote this example in action controller with parameters according to DB data, but now it generates HTML instead of PDF file. Did you had similar experience?
Code: 
`$id = 5; $typ = 1; $this->View()->setTemplate(); $document = Shopware_Components_Document::initDocument($id, $typ); $document->render();`